# Is there a way to change/clean a variable inside a for cicle loop in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME="01-SM1,02-SM1Touch,03-Data"
for i in $(echo $RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME | sed "s/,/ /g");
    do
          /bin/az group deployment create --name Template2020 --RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME=$i
```

With this command I create 3 APP with 01-SM1 02-SM1Touch, 03-Data but I need to insert a piece of this array in another parameter in order to have SM1 SM1Touch Data withot the number and the "-" before the APP name INSIDE a for cicle, like below

```
 RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME="01-SM1,02-SM1Touch,03-Data"
for i in $(echo $RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME | sed "s/,/ /g");
    do
          /bin/az group deployment create --name Template2020 --RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME=$i --webappconf=$WEBAPPNAMEWITHOUTNUMBERANDMINUSBEFORE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for i in $(echo $RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME | sed "s/,/ /g");
 do
    echo $i
    export AZWEBAPPNAMENONUMBER=`echo "$i" | cut -c 4-`
```

This is the way I decided.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array for `RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME` instead of a string.
Then you can iterate over it instead of parsing it with `sed`.

Something like this :

```
RD_OPTIONS=(
"SM1"
"SM1Touch"
"Data"
)

for number in `seq -f "%02g" 1 ${#RD_OPTIONS[@]}`
do
    name=${RD_OPTIONS[$number-1]}
    full="$number-$name"
    echo "number: $number"
    echo "name: $name"
    echo "full: $full"
done
```

will print

```
number: 01
name: SM1
full: 01-SM1
number: 02
name: SM1Touch
full: 02-SM1Touch
number: 03
name: Data
full: 03-Data
```

So you could do this :

```
RD_OPTIONS=(
"SM1"
"SM1Touch"
"Data"
)

for number in `seq -f "%02g" 1 ${#RD_OPTIONS[@]}`
do
    name=${RD_OPTIONS[$number-1]}
    full="$number-$name"
    /bin/az group deployment create --name Template2020 --RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME=$full --webappconf=$name
done
```

Comment: I can't choose to create an array because these are parameters from a web app that create multiple field selection with a comma separeted value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

```
RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME="01-SM1,02-SM1Touch,03-Data"
arr1=( ${RD_OPTION_AZWEBAPPNAME//,/' '} ) # conver your var to an array
arr2=( ${arr1[@]//*-/} )                  # create second array witn names SM1, SM1Touch, Data
arr3=( ${arr1[@]} ${arr2[@]} )            # create mega) array
for name in ${arr3[@]}; { your_code; }    # loop through mega array with your code
```

Comment: ./array.sh: 2: ./array.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: sh or bash? sh not support arrays, you need bash `#!/bin/bash`